# Computing net salary of employees using functions - C++

Tags: c++, function

Below is what I have thus far. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I think the input validation functions that I have are incorrect as well. Original problem is:

Write a program a program that would compute the net salary of employees. The program should prompt the user to input number of hours worked and the hourly wage.  Employees pay 17.5% of their gross salary as social security contribution. All employees pay 20% tax on their gross salary. Employees with gross salary less than 2500, pay 10% tax on their gross salary. Your program should use  the following functions;

a.  computeGross :This function calculates the gross salary based on the  number of hours worked and  hourly wage. The gross salary calculated is returned to the main function.

b.  computeDeductions: This function accepts as input , the gross salary , computes the social security and tax deductions and returns the total deductions to the main function

c.  computeNet: This function accepts as input the gross salary, deductions and prints out  The gross salary, total deductions and the net salary .

d.  validateHours: This function  is used for input validation. It determines if the number of hours provided by the user is valid or not. The number of hours worked in a pay period cannot exceed 150 and cannot be negative.

e.  validateWage: This function  is used for input validation. It determines if the hourly wage provided by the user is valid or not. The hourly wage cannot exceed 200 and cannot be negative.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// Declare Functions
double computeGross(double hoursWorked, double hourlyWage);
double computeDeductions(double grossPay);
double computeNet(double grossPay, double deductions);
void validateHours(double hoursWorked);
void validateWage(double hourlyWage);

int main()
{
    // Declare Variables
    double hoursWorked = 0;
    double hourlyWage = 0;
    double grossPay = 0;
    double deductions = 0;
    double netSalary = 0;

// Get the hours worked and hourly wage
cout << "Please enter the amount of hours worked (HH.MM): " << endl;
cin >> hoursWorked;
cout << "Please enter in your hourly wage: $" << endl;
cin >> hourlyWage;

// Output the results
cout << fixed << setprecision(2)
     << "The net salary is: $" << netSalary << endl;

    return 0;
}

// compteGross() function - get gross salary based on hours worked and hourly wage.
double computeGross(double grossPay, double hoursWorked, double hourlyWage)
{
return grossPay = hoursWorked * hourlyWage;
}

// computeDeductions() function - gets salary and calculates deductions
double computeDeductions(double deductions, double grossPay)
{

    if(grossPay < 2500)
    {
    deductions = (grossPay * .10) * .175;
    }
    else
    {
    deductions = (grossPay * .20) * .175;
    }

return deductions;

}

// computeNet() function - prints out gross salary,total deductions and net    salary
double computeNet(double netSalary, double grossPay, double deductions)
{
netSalary = grossPay - deductions;

cout << "The gross salary is: $" << grossPay << endl;
cout << "The total deductions are: $" << deductions << endl;
cout << "The net salary is: $" << netSalary << endl;
return netSalary;
}

// validateHours() function - input validation; hours worked can;t exceed 150  or be neg.
void validateHours(double hoursWorked)
{
    if(hoursWorked < 0 || hoursWorked > 150)
    {
        cout << "Error! Hours can't be negative or exceed 150\n";
    }
}

// validateWage() - Input validation; wage can't exceed 200 or be   negative
void validateWage(double hourlyWage)
{
    if(hourlyWage < 0 || hourlyWage > 200)
    {
    cout << "Error! Wage can't be negative or exceed 200\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your *specific* question?

Comment: When I run the program, I get 0 as the net salary, and no, my inputs are not 0. I'm trying to figure out why that is the case.

Comment: Please take some time out to lean how to use a debugger.   Step through the code,examine variables, etc.

Comment: @OldProgrammer you are old timer you might need glasses :) he is not calling any function from main() :) no debugger can help him debug a code he is not calling :)

Comment: No, but should will make the lack of said calls pretty smurfing obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to actually call your functions in your main functions for them to do anything.

For example:

```
    int main(){
    // Declare Variables
    double hoursWorked = 0;
    double hourlyWage = 0;
    double grossPay = 0;
    double deductions = 0;
    double netSalary = 0;

    // Get the hours worked and hourly wage
    cout << "Please enter the amount of hours worked (HH.MM): " << endl;
    cin >> hoursWorked;
    cout << "Please enter in your hourly wage: $" << endl;
    cin >> hourlyWage;

    //you have to actually call your functions lol:

    validateHours (hoursWorked);

    validateWage(hourlyWage);

    grossPay = computeGross(grossPay, hoursWorked, hourlyWage);

    deductions = computeDeductions(grossPay);

    netSalary = computeNet(netSalary,grossPay, deductions );

    // Output the results
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2)
    << "The net salary is: $" << netSalary << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Also, when you declare your functions before your main function you have to make sure they have the same number of parameters when you actually create the function bodies later on.

For example:
You define this in the beginning:

```
double computeNet(double grossPay, double deductions);
```

then later you have this when making the function body:

```
double computeNet(double netSalary, double grossPay, double deductions)
```

You also shouldn't cout in user defined functions imo, but you should be fine with this assignment. Have you learned about reference variables yet? It looks like a few of the things you are trying to do could benefit from them.

**EDIT:** I think I fixed it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// Declare Functions
double computeGross( double hoursWorked, double hourlyWage);
double computeDeductions(double grossPay);
double computeNet( double grossPay, double deductions);
void validateHours(double hoursWorked);
void validateWage(double hourlyWage);

int main()
{
    // Declare Variables
    double hoursWorked = 0;
    double hourlyWage = 0;
    double grossPay = 0;
    double deductions = 0;
    double netSalary = 0;

    // Get the hours worked and hourly wage
    cout << "Please enter the amount of hours worked (HH.MM): " << endl;
    cin >> hoursWorked;
    cout << "Please enter in your hourly wage: $" << endl;
    cin >> hourlyWage;

    //you have to actually call your functions lol:

    validateHours (hoursWorked);

    validateWage(hourlyWage);

    grossPay = computeGross(hoursWorked, hourlyWage);

    deductions = computeDeductions(grossPay);

    netSalary = computeNet(grossPay, deductions );

    // Output the results
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2)
    << "The net salary is: $" << netSalary << endl;

    return 0;
}

// compteGross() function - get gross salary based on hours worked and hourly wage.
double computeGross(double hoursWorked, double hourlyWage)
{
    return hoursWorked * hourlyWage;
}

// computeDeductions() function - gets salary and calculates deductions
double computeDeductions(double grossPay)
{
    double deductions;
    if(grossPay < 2500)
    {
        deductions = (grossPay * .10) * .175;
    }
    else
    {
        deductions = (grossPay * .20) * .175;
    }

    return deductions;

}

// computeNet() function - prints out gross salary,total deductions and net    salary
double computeNet(double grossPay, double deductions)
{
    double netSalary;
    netSalary = grossPay - deductions;

    cout << "The gross salary is: $" << grossPay << endl;
    cout << "The total deductions are: $" << deductions << endl;
    cout << "The net salary is: $" << netSalary << endl;
    return netSalary;
}

// validateHours() function - input validation; hours worked can;t exceed 150  or be neg.
void validateHours(double hoursWorked)
{
    if(hoursWorked < 0 || hoursWorked > 150)
    {
        cout << "Error! Hours can't be negative or exceed 150\n";
    }
}

// validateWage() - Input validation; wage can't exceed 200 or be   negative
void validateWage(double hourlyWage)
{
    if(hourlyWage < 0 || hourlyWage > 200)
    {
        cout << "Error! Wage can't be negative or exceed 200\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never actually called any of your functions. After you receive your final input from the user you should start calling the functions to calculate your results, then it should work.

The reason it only prints out 0 is because you set netSalary to 0, then never did anything to manipulate the variable to any other value.